# Typescript global app state to app instance

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, vuejs2, vue-component

I am new to typescript, and I am developing a WebGL viewer and facing an issue with a global variable for the app.

The issue is like this, WebGL viewer will be the Vue component so that multiple components can be inserted on the same page. I want to store the canvas context and some other data as global data so that I can be accessed in all my ".ts" file by just importing it. Since I tried to use two components on same page, the global state meshes up with each other.

Sample code here

```
class AppState {
    static CanvasID: string;
}


class viewer
{
   constructor(canvasID: string)
   {
     AppState.CanvasID = canvasID;
   }

   getCanvasID()
   {
      return AppState.CanvasID;
   }

}

class app
{
  public viewer: viewer;
  constructor(canvasID: string)
  {
    this.viewer = new viewer(canvasID)
  }
  getCanvasID()
  {
    return this.viewer.getCanvasID();
  }

}



function clientCode() {

   var app1 = new app("id1");

   alert(app1.getCanvasID());

   var app2 = new app("id2");    
   alert(app2.getCanvasID());

   alert(app1.getCanvasID());

}

clientCode();
```

In the above code, you can see that the value of "AppState.CanvasID" gets changed when I create new app instance(app2).

I want "AppState" to be local to the each instance and i want "AppState" to be imported in multiple .ts files and use like global.

I am using rollup to build as esm module.

Please provide your suggestion on this.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you made AppState.CanvasId static.  So no matter how many instances of the class they are all pointing to the same reference (you don’t even create new AppStates so in retro in should be more obvious it’s the same reference.). Change that to not be static and you should be fine. Note that you will need to create a new instance of AppState in each viewer similar to how you created a viewer in the app class.

But if you really wanted it static, you could use Map as in this example.  Note I changed "CanvasID" to "CanvasIDs"

```
class AppState {
    static CanvasIDs: Map<viewer, string> = new Map<viewer,string>();
}


class viewer
{
   constructor(canvasID: string)
   {
       AppState.CanvasIDs.set(this, canvasID);
   }

   getCanvasID()
   {
      return AppState.CanvasIDs.get(this);
   }

}

class app
{
  public viewer: viewer;
  constructor(canvasID: string)
  {
    this.viewer = new viewer(canvasID)
  }
  getCanvasID()
  {
    return this.viewer.getCanvasID();
  }

}



function clientCode() {
  console.log("test")
   var app1 = new app("id1");

   alert(app1.getCanvasID());

   var app2 = new app("id2");    
   alert(app2.getCanvasID());

   alert(app1.getCanvasID());

}

clientCode();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. AppState will have not only canvasID but also some other variables which will be used in multiple class just by importing the Appstate.ts file. For that reason only I kept the canvasID as static. In your case, if i want to access the canvasID in some other class then I need the viewer object but the class where I want to use the canvasID  will not have access to the viewer object.

Comment: I'm not totally sure I follow.  You would have access to all the canvas ids by doing AppState.CanvasIDs.keys(), you wouldn't need a viewer to look at them.